# Angular directive only updating class on one directive

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I created a directive to add classes to my table filters th elements.

```
app.directive('tableFilter', function () {
return {
    link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
        element.html(attrs.text + ' <i class="fa fa-unsorted"></i>');
        icon = element.children();


        scope.$watch('reverse', function (oldVal, val) {
            console.log(icon);
            if (angular.isDefined(oldVal)) {
                console.log(val);
                if (val) {
                    icon.addClass('fa-sort-asc');
                    icon.removeClass('fa-sort-desc');
                } else {
                    icon.removeClass('fa-sort-asc');
                    icon.addClass('fa-sort-desc');
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
});
```

I have 2 th's where I use this directive. The HTML is as follows.

```
<tr>
    <th table-filter ng-click="tableFilter = 'name'; reverse=!reverse" text="Name"></th>
    <th table-filter ng-click="tableFilter = 'created'; reverse=!reverse" text="Date"></th>
</tr>
```

If I click on a th the class will be added and removed, but only to the th where text="Date".
Everything goes right, except that the directive only adds or removes the class on the last th.

It is possible that this has something to do with the element.children()?

Hope you can help me.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Not the answer, but it could be a problem: The arguments to the listener function in $watch are newValue, oldValue. You seem to have them in the reverse order.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is because of the `icon = ...`.

Defining it that way, makes `icon` a global, so every time you call `icon = element.children()`, `icon` will be updated with that element's children.

You should make it a local variable, like this:

```
var icon = ...;
```

---

<sub>**<fun-spoiler>**

Not directly related to your question, but there are still several problems with your implementation.

E.g.:

1. The arguments to `$watch()`'s callback are reversed (as `Sunil D` mentioned), i.e. `newVal` comes before `oldVal`.

2. Upon clicking on a `th`, all icons are updated (which won't make much sense to the user as they won't know which column the table is sorted by).

**</fun-spoiler>**</sub>

---

<sub>**<major-fun-spoiler>**

**[Demo implementation](http://jsfiddle.net/ExpertSystem/WvrPU/)**.

(**Note:** It is not a good idea to have a reusable component such as `table-filter` share the scoe with its parent. It introduces tight coupling. You should use an isolate scope and create 2-way data-binding for `tableFilter` and `reverse`. But that's another story...)

**</major-fun-spoiler>**</sub>

Comment: @guidsen You should look into using "use strict"; in your JavaScript to be notified about problems like this immediately and save yourself some headaches.

Comment: Thanks, that worked. I thought that my directive would only update the children on the element so it only added the class to the children. But it seems it does for both ths. Any idea how to add the class only the the th child and not both?

Comment: One common approach is to check if the current value of `tableFilter` matches the filter-name associated to the clicked element. But for this to become possible you need to change your implementation (e.g. change `tableFilter` **after** checking against the element's filter-name). If `tableFilter` matches the clicked element's filter-name, you set `reverse=!reverse`.

Comment: @guidsen: A code-block is better than a 1000 words, so take a look at my updated answer for a link to a sample implementation of what I (tried to) describe(d) above :)